# How to trigger onChange event dynamically using JavaScript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am fetching data from my DB. I need when data has fetched one JavaScript function will called through onChange event. Here is my code:

```
<?php
  $id=$_GET['ids'];
  if($id!=""){
    $getcustomerobj = $dbobj->getFeedbackData($db,$id);
   }
?>

  <div style="width:24%; float:left; padding:10px;">Answer Type : 
<select class="form-control" id="answer_type" name="answer_type" onChange="selectScale(this.value);">
<option value="">Select Answer Type</option>
 <?php
$ustatus=array("status"=>'1');
$feeddata=$db->kf_answertype->find($ustatus);
 foreach($feeddata as $v){
?>
<option value="<?php echo $v['_id']; ?>" <?php if($getcustomerobj->answer_type == $v['_id'] or $_REQUEST['answer_type'] == $v['_id']){ print 'selected'; } ?>><?php echo $v['answertype']; ?></option>                          
 <?php } ?>
</select>
</div>
 <div style="width:24%; float:left; padding:10px; display:none;" id="scaleid">Scale :
<select class="form-control" id="nscale" name="noofscale"> 
<option value="">Select No Of Scale</option>
<?php
$status=array("status"=>'1');
 $feeddata=$db->kf_scale->find($ustatus);
 foreach($feeddata as $v){
 ?>
<option value="<?php echo $v['_id']; ?>" <?php if($getcustomerobj->no_of_scale == $v['_id'] or $_REQUEST['no_of_scale'] == $v['_id']){ print 'selected'; } ?>><?php echo $v['noofscale']; ?></option>                           
     <?php } ?>
  </select>
 </div>

<script>
  function selectScale(id){
    console.log('select scale',id);
    var data=$.param({'op':'getscale','sid':id});
    $.ajax({
        method:'POST',
        url:"dbcon/DBConnection.php",
        data:data
    }).done(function(msg){
        //console.log('msg',msg);
        var dedata=JSON.parse(msg);
        //console.log('decode',dedata);
        if(dedata[0]['data']==1){
            document.getElementById("scaleid").style.display="block";
        }
        if(dedata[0]['data']==0){
            document.getElementById("scaleid").style.display="none";
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Here I need when data are fetching from DB the `Answer Type` drop down field will set with some value. As the second drop down list (i.e. `Scale`) is depends on first drop down, I need to call `selectScale` function which has triggered using onChange event.

Comment: `onChange()` event can be manually triggered like this, `$('#answer_type').change()`. this will call the change event for answer_type dropdown.

Comment: How i will do this in PHP. My requirement is when user getting data using ` $getcustomerobj = $dbobj->getFeedbackData($db,$id);`the function should called.

Comment: PHP is server side and Javascript is client side. You cannot call Javascript from php. It works the other way around.

Comment: So how can i resolve this.

Comment: well actually you need to echo the js script to call change event inside php script, but the potential issue i can see is that your answer_type dropdown php script will be executed after your this code `$getcustomerobj = $dbobj->getFeedbackData($db,$id);`, so if your placing your change code here, then it will not work properly. i hope your able to visualize it.

Comment: How can i do that.

Comment: call the change event after the data is populated into answer_type dropdown. `</select> <?php
        echo "
            <script type=\"text/javascript\"> $('#answer_type').change()
            </script>
        ";
  ?>`

Comment: @dreamweiver : I added like this `<?php 
               if($getcustomerobj->answer_type !=''){
                 echo " <script type=\"text/javascript\"> $('#answer_type').change() </script> ";
               }
             ?>` but it gave me this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: selectScale is not defined` .

Comment: well thats expected because `selectScale()` function is defined after at the end of the html page, place that script inside the `head` tag, so that it will be available before change event is triggered

Comment: i solved this.thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can call onchange event for your first drop-down on document ready so based on this your second drop-down value will be selected.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#answer_type").trigger("change");
    });
```

may be this is helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

As what i have understood ,what you need is simply add this line to your java script

```
selectScale($('#answer_type').val());
```

Also this solution could work, by triggering change function using jQuery

```
$("#answer_type").trigger("change");
```

Comment: @ SamyMassoud : Here i need suppose `Answer Type` drop down has set the data from DB using `<?php if($getcustomerobj->answer_type == $v['_id'] or $_REQUEST['answer_type'] == $v['_id']){ print 'selected'; } ?>><?php echo $v['answertype']; ?></option>                          
 <?php } ?` the given function should call autometically.